# Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How come it doesn't show any error passing the title and description but it shows a  **Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined"** on content.link.text

**Parent**

```
<template>
 <div>
  <splash :content="Splash"></splash>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from './Child.vue'

export default {
    name: 'Main',

    data () {
        Splash: {},
    },

    created () {
        const ax = axios.create({
        baseURL: '/static'
        })
        ax.get('content.json')
        .then(res => {

            this.Splash = res.data.general.splash

        })
    },

    components: {
        Splash
    }
   }
</script>
```

**Child**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">


        <h2>{{ content.title }}</h2>     // ok
        <p>{{ content.description }}</p> // ok              
        <p>{{ content.link.text }}</p>   // shows render error  
    </div>
</template>
<script>


export default {

    name: 'Splash',

    props: [
        'content'
    ]



}
</script>
```

**content.json**

```
{
    general : {
        splash : {
         "title" : "lorem title",
         "description" : "lorem description",
         "link" : { 
           "text" : "click me"
         }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is due to the value of `content` on first render.  That is an empty object, which will return undefined for any property

```
content = {}
link = content.link // link is undefined
link.text // error
```

You should have a condition for first rendering so that you don't display the content unless it has a valid value.

---

Expanding

Your promise is in the created hook, but due to it being async it will only return data at some point after the current sync cycle finishes.  By that time the Splash component will have already been created with the object that will cause the error.

If you are going to be doing a pattern like this where you will be fetching real data there are a few patterns you can use depending on how you want the user flow to work.

1. Use lodash _.get to wrap all of your data that may or may not be there.  Then your `content.link.text` would go in the computed properties and be something like `return _.get(content, 'link.text')`.  This will cause it to properly return a value here.
2. Don't render the Splash until the async request is complete, while loading show a loading
3. Use v-if in your Splash component to guard

Out of these, i would say 2 is the best b/c it splits the concerns.

Comment: Can you explain me a bit more how it works? .. so basically I used the created hook.. to assign the content from the json file to an object before rendering.. I thought after that, it renders the content but now the content wont be empty anymore...even though I don't get any error message on content.title or content.description.. it happens just in objects inside the content

Comment: Will expand answer

Answer (score 2):

@Ausito already provided the answer. But I thought i'd put in an example.
 
Set `Splash` to `null` as default and put in `v-if="Splash"` in the `splash` component.

```
<template>
 <div>
  <splash v-if="Splash" :content="Splash"></splash>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from './Child.vue'

export default {
    name: 'Main',

    data () {
        Splash: null,
    },

    created () {
        const ax = axios.create({
        baseURL: '/static'
        })
        ax.get('content.json')
        .then(res => {
            this.Splash = res.data.general.splash
        })
    },

    components: {
        Splash
    }
   }
</script>
```