# How can I create dynamic menu with submenu in vue 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem and if you can help me I would be grateful, because I am working with vue for 3 weeks.

I try to create a menu with submenu in vue 2 by two weeks and I can't succeed. the menu is created , but when I go to submenu is won't create it. the code is next:

```js
<script>
import image from "./assets/img/logo-just-escape.png"
import axios from "axios"

 export default {
        data(){
          const lang = localStorage.getItem('lang')
            return {
                imagel: image,
                lang: lang,
                languages:null,
                menu:null,
                submenu:null
            }
        },
        async created(){
          try {
            
            var res =await axios.get(`lng`);
            this.languages=res.data;

            const valmenu="titles/value?language="+this.lang;
            res=await axios.get(valmenu);
            this.menu=res.data;
            this.submenu=this.getSubMnu(this.menu);
            console.log(this.submenu)
          }catch(e){
              console.error(e);
          }
        },
        methods: {
              handleChange(event){
                localStorage.setItem('lang',event.target.value);
                window.location.reload();
              },
              getSubMnu(value){
                let temp='';
                let sbmenu=[];
                let variable=null;
                for(temp in value){                  
                  if('2'==value[temp].subtitle){
                    variable=value[temp];
                    let temp1=value[temp].link+"\/"+this.menu[temp].id;
                    variable.link=temp1;
                    sbmenu.push(variable);
                  }
                }
              return sbmenu;
              }
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="app" class="bg-dark">
    <div>
          <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
            
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
              <img width="100" height="50" :src="imagel"/>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <div v-for="menuButton in this.menu" :value="menuButton.title" :key="menuButton.id">
                  <li class="nav-item" v-if="menuButton.subtitle ===0">
                    <router-link :to="menuButton.link" ><span class="nav-link">{{menuButton.title}}</span></router-link>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown" v-if="menuButton.subtitle ===1" style="color: white;">
                      <span class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">{{menuButton.title}}</span>
                     <div v-for="tempor in this.submenu" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right bg-dark" :value="tempor.title" :key="tempor.id">
                       <span class="nav-link">{{tempor.title}}</span>
                        <router-link :to="tempor.link" @click.name><span class="nav-link">{{tempor.title}}</span></router-link>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                </div>
               
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <select class="selectpicker form-control" v-model="lang" data-width="fit" @change="handleChange($event)">
                       <option v-for="langu in languages" :value="langu.language_short" :key="langu.id">
                      {{langu.language}}
                    </option>

                    </select>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          
          </nav>

      <div class="divmargin" >
         
        <router-view/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'submenu' of undefined"

found in

--->  at src/App.vue

If someone can give me some answer to this I will be very grateful.

Thank you,
Vlad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53154332/error-in-render-typeerror-cannot-read-property-text-of-undefined)

Comment: Sadly I tried even what it writes there, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Well Until the end was a problem of rendering the page and classes , thank you anyway.

Comment: In that case, post it as an answer, reading [answer].